# Suppressing WARNING message when importing ImportExcel on Chromebook

Tags: powershell

This feels like it should be pretty simple but this pesky WARNING message will not go away!

This is the command:

```
Import-module ImportExcel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue > $null
```

So I've tried to suppress all output to the console and even sent any output to `$null` and I still get the following:

[image]

I'm not worried about the warning - how do I do the Import but side step the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The [common `-WarningAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-warningaction) applies to the warnings emitted by the target cmdlet *itself*.
- It is conceivable that the warning you're seeing is emitted by *the module being imported*.
- Using [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `3>$null` - which targets [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) number `3`, the warning stream - should help in that case.

```bash
# Use 3>$null to silence all warnings.
Import-Module ImportExcel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 3>$null
```